# How can I check the aspect ratio of a website user's display?

Tags: javascript

Is there a possible way to check the aspect ratio of a website user's screen (4:3, 16:9 etc.) in JavaScript or other web languages?

Comment: What do you mean "of a user"? Pants size? Are you asking about the physical screen size, or the browser viewport?

Comment: i basically mean the resolution of their screen size and how to check if its a 4:3 screen or 16:9 etc

Comment: You don't have access to the hardware dimensions.

Comment: well i think the browser viewport is always the same size so you can calculate it. but then, how can i check their browser viewport?

Comment: That's a question that has been asked and answered many times on SO.

Comment: Do you want the aspect ratio of the browser or the screen, there's a difference ?

Comment: Keep in mind this value can change wildly if they're on a device with variable orientation like a tablet or a phone.

Answer (score 1):

This two variables will give you height and width, which can be used to get resolution or aspect ratio:

```
  var width = screen.width;
  var height = screen.height;
```